# Printing Receipt from Django Web Application

Tags: javascript, css, django, printing

I am developing a web-based POS. Unfortunately, POS must print through a thermal receipt printer (TM-T88IV, Epson). The web application is based on Django. Is there any idea on how the system could automatically print a receipt whenever a user clicks a control in the web application?

I was thinking of creating other services in python for that purpose, but that would defeat the purpose of having a web application, where all you need is a browser, without any extra installation.

The printer is connected to the client by the way, and the printing should be "silently" triggered, which means that there is no need for human intervention. Once the transaction is finalized, the printing should starts.

Any suggestion is welcomed!

Comment: Is the printer connected to the server or to the client?

Comment: Oh, indeed, it's not that clear. If he knows what the printer is, it's probably server-side... (which in turn would mean that my answer sucks.) PHP can print "natively" on the server, but it only works on old versions of Windows. On Linux, it would probably be easier to print using the command line.

Comment: @Spacedman it is connected to the client.

Comment: Have you seen my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12252104/1312346

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two ways to accomplish it:

### First method - Configure your browser

#### Notes

Good solution if you have one printer for every client (because you can use the default printer only). Keep in mind that you can remove your print server (useful for very resource limited devices) making a script that the browser should automatically execute for open your file. You can use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
printer="/dev/usb/lp0"
encoding_needed=true #false

if $encoding_needed; then
    iconv -c -t 437 $1 > $printer
else
    cat $1 > $printer
fi
```

#### Firefox

- Manual setup:

  1. Open about:config
  2. Create a new boolean value called `print.always_print_silent` and set it to `True`
  3. Create a new boolean value called `print.show_print_progress` and set it to `False`
- Use an extension, like: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/attendprint/

Keep in mind that there are other extensions for making kiosks, for example:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/
- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/mkiosk/

#### Chrome

You can start it with those options: `--kiosk --kiosk-printing`

#### Internet Explorer

For kiosk mode see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154780

### Second method - Server handles every printer

#### Notes

Good solution if:

1. You have more clients than printers (few money or faulty printers)
2. More printers than clients (different printers or paper colors for different needs)
3. Clients that can't print directly (PDA/smartphones)
4. You want to know the printer status

#### How to do

1. Connect printers (to the clients and/or to the server)
2. Share printers connected to clients over the network
3. Manage every printer from your Django server

Comment: I chose the second method (not exactly same) but I create a daemon/service in each client that listen to any printing request from the web app server.

Answer (score 6):

Two options here: print an html page or provide a PDF file.

Note: it was not clear initially that prints should be automatic, which means the answer is not directly useful to OP.

### HTML + "Print Me"

Show the receipt as an html page, then create a `media="print"` CSS stylesheet which the browser will use when printing the receipt. There's [a lot to say about CSS print style sheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/), but what's important is that you should remove all navigation elements and images that are going to be expensive to print.

When you do this, the user will simply have to print the page himself. You can also add a "Print Me" button which is going to show your user a printer dialog. This is done via JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print this page</a>
```

(This is a bit obstrusive for your clients who don't have JS, check [this tutorial about JS printing](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/how_to_create_an_unobtrusive_print_this_page_link_with_javascript/) for a better way.)

### PDF

Generate a PDF in Django, and show it to the user. He will be free to print it or save it on his computer later. Most web sites do this since it's far easier to control the layout of a PDF file, and it will be easier to make it look like a real receipt.

- [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) can help you do this (it translates an XML to a PDF with a "stylesheet").
- A more Pythonic way seems to be explained in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/)
- The above pages lists alternatives such as xhtml2pdf (Pisa) which seems to be used a lot on StackOverflow

Comment: Great solution but I am planning to do it silently, without having to show the user the PDF or the HTML windows. When the transaction is finalized, the receipt printing starts to kick in. Is this possible?

Comment: It is not possible from the web. I would not want any web application to use my printer without me allowing it first!

Comment: guess I have to go back to desktop application...was about to be happy to use the Django awesome ORM in the POS ><

Comment: The user only has to click on "OK". Is that really too much?

Comment: It is too much when you have people in queue plus the overhead from generating the PDF from the data extracted over the network. If you are familiar with receipt printing, it is really straightforward where u flush a sequence of hex codes but I just don't know how to it from browser.

Comment: I have to admit I know nothing about receipt printing. What you really should do next is working out this printing problem. Then you'll see what to build on top of it, be if desktop or web app (but there will always be something installed on the machine if you want it to print that easily). Maybe your printing server has a local (web?) API?

Comment: it would be great and easy if the printer uses ethernet connection but unfortunately, it uses only USB or serial interfaces :(

Comment: Yeah, but the computer could still provide an API for it, then communicating with the printer by USB. For example, CUPS has an HTTP API which you could use in JavaScript provided you bypass JS cross-domain security and provide the correct credentials http://cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.5/api-httpipp.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7685/discussion-between-cygal-and-haikal-nashuha)

Comment: Hi, @HaikalNashuha did you solve this problem? I also have concern the same as yours right now. I opened your chatbox to follow your conversation but the page is already removed. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: @aldesabido Yes, you can see how it is done in my comment under the marked as answer reply.

Answer (score 2):

If using raw/esc/p try jzebra on google code.