# How to send command to receipt printers from Django app?

Tags: python, django, printing, receipt

I have created a simple POS application. I now have to send a command to the receipt printer to print the receipt. I don't have any code related to this problem as I don't know where to start even. My questions are:

1) Is Windows a good choice for working with receipt printers as every shop I went to use a desktop application on Windows for POS?

2) Is it possible to control the receipt printer and cash register/drawer from a web app?

3) Is there a good reading material for developing POS systems by myself?

Comment: Do you want to print from the client, or the server?

Comment: Also take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374322/is-it-possible-redirect-user-to-launch-scanner-application/30374741#30374741

Comment: Well the server will have the app and the client will use it from the POS stations. So the printing has to be done in the client PC. But if printing from the server is an easier solution I want to know that too.

Comment: Seems duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257580/printing-receipt-from-django-web-application?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

For a web app to use a device on the client, it has to go through the browser. I may be wrong, but I seriously doubt this is a built-in feature for receipt printers. I see three options:

1) Find/make a normal printer driver that works with your receipt printer, put it on the client box, and just use the normal print js commands.

2) Find/make a browser plugin that talks to the printer and exposes an API.

3) Find/make a simple web app that talks to a server-connected receipt printer (probably via native code execution or script call), and install it on each POS, with CORS to allow remote origin; then just post to that on `127.0.0.1:whatever` from the webapp client script.

Side note: I seriously discourage connecting a POS to anything resembling a network any more than absolutely necessary. Every outbound network request or trusted network peer is a potential attack vector. In short, I would never use django or any other web app for physical POS software.